# Loading big image make the app laggy [Glide]

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm trying to load a big image **(4000x6000)** from gallery to my app, with **Glide** and the code below, the app become super laggy.

```
 public static int IMAGE_SIZE = Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL;

 Glide.with(BaseActivity.this).asBitmap().load(path).fitCenter().into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            bitmapProgresses.add(new Progress(resource, getResources().getString(R.string.Original)));
            contentAfterLoad(resource);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
        }
    });
```

However, when I change the `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL` to a specific value, for example, **2000**, the app become smooth, but the output bitmap resizes to less than 2000px.

**My Question :**

Is there any way to load a big image into my app as the photo editor apps do?

Comment: Your `ImageView` will not be 4000px on either side, let alone 6000px. Also, you may not have ~90MB of contiguous heap space available for an image of that size. What do you intend to do with the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your comment, my app is a photo editor, so the saved image should be the same as the input one, if the user decides to edit an image with 4000x6000, in that case, I need to make the saved image have the same size

Comment: You should resize the image just enough to user do you things in a good size, to the any device can load the image and record the steps user and process into the original image

Comment: @FelipeCustódio Thank you, and yeah I thought the same, but I just wonder if there's a way without doing that

Comment: "my app is a photo editor" -- my guess is that you will need to handle this at least in part using C/C++ and the NDK. That's the only way that you will be able to handle the memory requirements in a reliable fashion.